# How to build a relationship with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, relationship

I have two SQL tables:

```
Users ( Id, Username )
Profiles ( Id, UserId, Email )
```

I have two classes:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public Profile profile { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
    //[Key]
    //public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I have a View that selects Users and Profiles as a JOIN:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Users]
AS SELECT 
    AspNetUsers.UserName, 
    UserProfiles.*
FROM [AspNetUsers]
INNER JOIN UserProfiles ON AspNetUsers.Id = UserProfiles.UserId
```

How do I relate (in the classes) the User to the Profile so that I can use the EntityFramework controller/view crud builder?

Comment: This is not how EF works. You can (and should) populate the classes directly form the database tables. you don't need the view. If you work code-first you can readily use your class model (without the comments, of course) and the tables.

Comment: The view was a red herring. it's really just doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Relationships and views are different things.
You can have actual views, or have queries that return table X and table Y combined in the result.
See Projection via the "select" method.

[relationships explained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620)

[Working with relationships](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564)

[sample projection query](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Worth spending a few hours on the [THE EF SITE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef)
if you are serious about using EF.